# Getting the session value from memcached for a laravel session

Tags: php, session, laravel-4, memcached

I have a laravel app configured to store sessions in memcached.

I can get the session id in a view by printing `Session::getId()`, but when I telnet to the memcached instance i can not get that session value, by using `get value_from_Session::getId()`

Does laravel use a different key in memcached for storing the session as I am not able to retrive that session from memcached directly?

The `'prefix' => ''` is set to empty in cache.php in the laravel app

Comment: `Session::get('id')`?

Comment: Session::get('id') would return the value of the id key, if there was one. Does not return the session id. `Session::getId()` is right, but something goes on while the store in memcached happens modifying the session key. Maybe the key is not the session id?